# How to redirect the users based on there roles laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Hello their i am using laravel 5.1 and i have problem with redirecting the path of user. i have a roles table, a users table and role_user table means pivot table. Every thing is fine nice but i failed to redirect the page of different user. . This is my User Model. I have not created any middleware

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('my\role');
}


public function hasRole($role) 
{
    if (is_string($role)){

        return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
    }

    return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}
```

This is my `AuthController`:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    // Logic that determines where to send the user
    if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('GlobalAdmin', 'SuperAdmin', 'CompanyAdmin', 'GroupAdmin'))
    {
        return '/adminpanel';
    }

    return '/dashboard';
}
```

When I login as role `globleadmin` It works fine and redirect to adminpanel but when i login as another assigned role it redirect to dashboard. I didn't get it perhaps I passed arguments in `AuthController` as:

```
 if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('GlobalAdmin', 'SuperAdmin', 'CompanyAdmin', 'GroupAdmin'))
```

is incorrect. Please help me.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/adminpanel', 'Admin\adminscontroller@index');
```

And This is my adminscontroller:

```
class adminscontroller extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Admin.AdminPanel');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.